# Why won't this php string just explode?

Tags: php, explode

I am trying to explode :

```
$national_retail_propertiesRecord['leasing_inquiries']
```

which when var dumped originally is:

```
string(7) " 35 34 "
```

I am exploding it by using:

```
$leasingsInqueries = explode(" ", $national_retail_propertiesRecord['leasing_inquiries']);
```

The subsequent explosion is var_dumped and looks like so:

```
var_dump($leasingsInqueries);

array(1) { [0]=> string(7) " 35 34 " }
```

Why won't it make individual strings out of each number?

Any one here good with explosives?

Comment: Are you sure that the character is a standard space character?

Comment: how can i be sure if its standard? (sorry if noob question) The two numbers come from a database and are saved as a text field together.

Comment: That code works just fine for me. http://codepad.org/TXtA4sn2 Have you tried casting the value as a string by putting (string) before it in the call to explode()?

Comment: `for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($national_retail_propertiesRecord['leasing_inquiries']); $i++) {
    echo ord($national_retail_propertiesRecord['leasing_inquiries'][$i]), ' ';
}` - if you see 32 for the space characters, then it's a normal space

Comment: the trim gets rid of the leading and tail space but it still remains a string

Comment: i get 9 for the spaces...so they aren't spaces?

Comment: &nbsp; did not work either =(...looking into the this 9 thing

Comment: so its not &#009; either

Comment: If you get 9 for the "space": `$leasingsInqueries = explode("\x09", $national_retail_propertiesRecord['leasing_inquiries']);`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So thanks to Marks handy advice in the comments i discovered by using

```
for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($national_retail_propertiesRecord['leasing_inquiries']); $i++) { echo ord($national_retail_propertiesRecord['leasing_inquiries'][$i]), ' '; }
```

That my "space" was actually a horizontal tab indicated by the ASCII symbol 9 which the php snippet above outputted for me.

originally i tried the ASCII value for "tab" which is : `&#009;` but manually adding in my own tab : `explode("  ",` Worked perfectly

Credit goes to https://stackoverflow.com/users/324584/mark-baker for helping me with that!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't know what the seperator is, then you could use [`preg_match_all`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to select all the integers in your string.

```
$string = ...;
preg_match_all("/\d+/", $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: This also works for me, but i wanted to figure out fundamentally why it wasn't working, but thank you for the quick answer!